# Передача в boost::aray константы вторым пораметром

Tags: c++, boost

Нужно передать длину массива с помощью константы. Желательно, чтобы она была не глобальной, например, статичекой. Пробовал.

1 вариант

header

```
    class Interface
    {
    static const unsigned int buffer_size;    
    virtual void func(boost::array<char, buffer_size> & buffer);
    }
```

source

```
#include "header.h"
const unsigned int ISocketConnection::buffer_size = 8192;
```

2 вариант

```
const unsigned int buffer_size = 8192;

class Interface
{
virtual void func(boost::array<char, buffer_size> & buffer);
}
```

Ни тот не другой вариант не работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно, чтобы в точке в точке декларации константа buffer_size уже была доступна компилятору в качестве constexpr выражения.

Если ваш компилятор достаточно новый, должно сработать:

```
#include <array>
class Interface
{
    static const unsigned int buffer_size=8192;    
    virtual void func(std::array<char, buffer_size> & buffer);
};
```

Если компилятор не позволяет определить константу внутри класса, есть старый прием:

```
#include <array>
class Interface
{
    enum { buffer_size=8192 };    
    virtual void func(std::array<char, buffer_size> & buffer);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще и шаблонный вариант:

```
template < int buffer_size > 
class I_f
{        
   virtual void func(boost::array<char, buffer_size> & buffer);
   //...
}

class  Interface : public I_f<8192> {//... };
```

Можно просто использовать    `I_f<8192>`